# React does not rerender component when state changes for a few milliseconds

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, render

I understand React state changes are queued and then processed. Is it possible that state changes can happen so fast that they are completely "skipped" and never rendered?

Let's assume I have some React state.

```js
// assume initial state is = originalState
setState(newState);
setState(originalState);
```

In this situation, the `newState` is queued to be rendered, but only for a few milliseconds before the `originalState` is queued and rendered again. Does React simply ignore that `newState`?

That's the behavior I'm seeing locally. In my use-case, I need to be able to clear the state and then immediately update it to force a piece of text to re-announce errors through a screen reader.

Comment: Depending on the context, the state change is sometimes batched. You can schedule state change with a `setTimeout` or by condition... Either way, you need to add a reproducible examples in Stackoverflow questions. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for - sounds like state changes *can* be batched. Thank you!

Comment: Just providing additional reading: https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2

Comment: This isn't how you use setState. setState does not run "when you call it", it runs "when the scheduler gets to it", and so you issue _one_ setState for each true state change, and that state will kick in "eventually" (and eventually might be entire milliseconds from now, but is usually <1ms). Never issue consecutive setState calls: that makes no sense. And yes, setState calls are aggregated: the state change is buffered until it's actually processed, so whatever is the state "at the time of that last setState" is what's getting committed as new state.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There isn't a reason to issue them right next to each other like in the example, but there might be situations where you're fetching some data from multiple places and want to update the same "state" each time you receive a different piece of information

Comment: That's not consecutive updates in the same (synchronous) code path, though. That's simply "updating the state as data comes in that warrants updating the state".